# zindex and child element

Tags: css, hover

http://jsfiddle.net/cxwQF/12/.

Note: Red and green boxes should intersect. Green box is image or video. When hover it became yellow. But not on the bottom where the red box starts. Red box is control (for example, next image).

Question. How can I put parent div behind the image and child div to the top.

Markup:

```
<div id='image'></div>
<div id='parent'>
    <div id='child'></div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#image {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: green;
    z-index: 2;
}

#image:hover {
    background: yellow;
}

#parent {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

/*#parent:hover {
    background: blue;
} */  

#child {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 3;
}​
```

Comment: Concerning your #child class.. For a z-index to be active you must change the position to either Fixed, Absolute or Relative.

Comment: agree, I've added "position: relative" to the #child element. Unfortunately, this doesn't make me closer to solution.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to make a second parent to put on top of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the pure CSS solution. Markup remains the same.

CSS:

```
#image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: green;
}

#image:hover {
    background: yellow;
}

#parent {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#child:hover {
    background: pink;
}

#child {
    margin: 0 auto;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}​
```

Solution: #parent's "visibility" should be set to "hidden", #child's "visibility" should be set to "visible"

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/cxwQF/22/

Answer (score 0):

How does this suit you? It's hard to know how to structure it without knowing what you are trying to achieve.

http://jsfiddle.net/cxwQF/21/

I've created another, invisible `div` for your 'child' but the original (foot) remains in the same place.

```
<div id='image'></div>
<div id='foot'>

</div>
<div id='parent'>
<div id='child'></div>
</div>
```

Sorry about the border styles its purely for test purposes.

Comment: To be honest I was searching for purely css solution. Intuitively, hierarchy should not affect z-index, but it does.